# less bundle is empty in production

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, azure, less, dotless

I use the following packages in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013:

- dotless
- bootstrap less source
- bundle transformer core
- bundle transformer less
- javascript engine switcher for .NET (core/msie)
- Web optimization framework

I create the following bundles in BundleConfig.cs:

```
var nullBuilder = new NullBuilder();
var styleTransformer = new StyleTransformer();
var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/less").Include("~/Content/master.less");
lessBundle.Builder = nullBuilder;
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(styleTransformer);
lessBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
bundles.Add(lessBundle);

var lessLandingBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/less-landing").Include("~/Content/landing.less");
lessLandingBundle.Transforms.Add(styleTransformer);
lessLandingBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
bundles.Add(lessLandingBundle);
```

This works on debug (true AND false). But when I publish the site to azure websites, I get an empty less file: `bundles/less?v=`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed dotless and the transformation pakcages and only used Web optimization framework. This way You can set the framework to compile the less code at build time.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely hitting [this bug in dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/418). Until it gets fixed, you can get around it by specifying `disableParameters="true"` in the `dotless` section of your Web.config.

Comment: If you've moved to using System.Web.Optimization.Less, it also exhibits this bug under certain conditions because it uses dotless internally.

Comment: Also, oops, the answer should have said disableParameters="true"